# Predicting on categorical values not used to estimate glm model in R

Tags: r, prediction, glm, predict

I have estimated a `glm` model and now looking to predict based on a new dataset. However, the new data has some variables (categorical variables) which were not in the original dataset. This gives the following mistake:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, 
xlev = object$xlevels) : factor Market has new levels TI
```

Is there anyway to circumvent within the predict e.g. `predict.glm` commands. I know I can test whether the levels are the same before I use predict and then insert something else, but it would be easier if there were built something into the function.

Comment: subset data set to the variables you have in the model

Comment: it's always a good practice to merge both training and testing data, set the levels of each factor variables and then again split it up, this would ensure that though that specifc level was just in test data but the train data has this as a level atleast

Comment: thanks for the answer joel.wilson. Sounds good. I actually already did that, so all the levels are already in there. I have made sure for the "test set", all dependent variables are simply set to NA as to be ignored during estimation, This however, still gives the error message.

Comment: @Mateusz1981, but this would make me lose a lot of information, which I cannot afford to lose.

Comment: You can install several R versions on your PC and running the one you want. If you use RStudio you can also select the R version you want to use